# Real life scenario in which detached object needs to be persisted: Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am learning hibernate and came to know the Object states which Hibernate maintains for `Entities`: `Transient` , `Persistent` , `detached`.

What would be the real life scenario in which we would want to have a `detached` object to be `persisted` again?

I referred online and one of the example is in which data is displayed in GUI then detached and once user makes the changes, the detached object is persisted again.

Can there be any other example other than this for better understanding?

Answer (score 1):

We had a scenario, because of some poor implemented design, were we need to make a call from within a transaction(`editJobPost`) in one service layer to another service layer(`checkSuspicion`) which had its own transaction.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { RuntimeException.class, EntityException.class })
public JobPostResponseDto editJobPost(EditJobPostRequestDto requestDto) throws EntityException {
    ...
    if (Constants.JOB_POST_ACTIONS.EDIT.equals(requestDto.getAction())) {
        jobPost = checkSuspicion(jobPost, jobPost.getJobType(), jobPost.getStatus(), requestDto); //checkSuspicion had its own transaction.
    }
    entityManager.merge(jobPost);
    ...
}
```

Now because of the ongoing transaction in method `editJobPost`  and then in `checkSuspicion` there were **detached** issues with the `entityManager`.

So we detached the `jobPost` entity from the first transaction and later merged it.

The updated method is as follows

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { RuntimeException.class, EntityException.class })
public JobPostResponseDto editJobPost(EditJobPostRequestDto requestDto) throws EntityException {
    ...
    entityManager.detach(jobPost); //object detached
    if (Constants.JOB_POST_ACTIONS.EDIT.equals(requestDto.getAction())) {
        jobPost = checkSuspicion(jobPost, jobPost.getJobType(), jobPost.getStatus(), requestDto); //checkSuspicion had its own transaction.
    }
    entityManager.merge(jobPost); //merged later
    ...
}
```

There must be other scenarios as well.

Hope this clears your doubt regarding the detached and later persisted entities.

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful, for example, when copying data from one database to another with some sort of processing.

We take an object from one session, detach it, change something, put this object to the second session.